# what should i do to display all data from 2 or more different table, i try to use JOIN but i still dont understand?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm not to good with English so please understand, and its my first time using this too, thank you so much ^^

I want to show all data from database to my view in CodeIgniter, but the problem is, the data I want to show to my view is from 2 or more different tables, I tried to use `JOIN` but I don't understand what it means. I successfully showed just 1 table, but I don't understand how to show from 2 or more table.

I have 2 tables:

1. data_skm_organisasi
   [table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzuSJ.png)
2. data_skm_kejuaraan
   [table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvJzl.png)

I want to show all data from 2 tables above

This is my code to show two or more data from my tables in database
and its show error

Controller

```
public function V_home()
{
   $dataOrganisasi = $this->M_main->getSKMorganisasi();  
   $dataSimpanOrganisasi = array();
   $dataSimpanOrganisasi ['organisasi']= $dataOrganisasi;
   $this->load->view('V_mahasiswa',$dataSimpanOrganisasi);
}
```

model

```
function getSKMorganisasi(){
   $query = $this->db->JOIN('data_skm_organisasi','data_skm_kejuaraan');
   $results = $this->db->get();     
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

view

```
<?php foreach ($organisasi as $dataSimpan) { ?>
   <div>
     <?php echo $dataSimpan->Lembaga; ?>
     <?php echo $dataSimpan->tingkatan; ?><br><br>
   </div>
     <?php } ?><br><br>

   <?php foreach ($organisasi as $dataSimpan) { ?>
   <div>
     <?php echo $dataSimpan->jenisKegiatan; ?>
     <?php echo $dataSimpan->tingkatan; ?><br><br>
   </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

This error shows up when I try to run

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near JOIN `data_skm_organisasi` USING (`data_skm_kejuaraan`) at line
>   2
>
> SELECT * JOIN `data_skm_organisasi` USING (`data_skm_kejuaraan`)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Aplikasi_SKM2/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: Please post your table structures as well and any/all primary/foreign keys in those tables. As for your query, the error you are getting is because the syntax is incorrect. It should be something like: `SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.foreign_key = t1.primary_key`

Comment: sir u can see now my table structures, i already edit my question, i have a new question where should i put that code u suggest to me? at my model or what?

Comment: What is the link between the 2 tables ? On which column(s) are the connected ? Or are they completely unrelated to one another ?

Comment: i dont know how to connect between the two tables, i think they completely unrelated, since i made the two tables without knowing the basic i just create the database to save my data when i want to upload something.

Comment: Is there any where clause in your query ? Something to limit the number of the result you will get ? One example of connecting 2 table would be to have a `Users` table which has a field `ID` and another table called `UserData` that has a field `UserID` and than those 2 fields would be used to connect those 2 tables

Comment: i dont know what do you mean, but i have a field name `Id` in each table it was my `primary key` and i dont understand what `foreign key` means too.. i think i should learn the basic about database before ask a question like this.it goes nowhere and you probably need to explain in detail too so i think thats enough help ..... thank you sir for your help..i really apreciate it... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could connect these 2 tables and display all of the data in them by using `JOIN` is like this:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM data_skm_organisasi AS table1
LEFT JOIN data_skm_kejuaraan AS table2 ON table1.namaKegiatan = table2.namaKegiatan AND table1.namaMahasiswa AND table2.namaMahasiswa
ORDER BY table1.id ASC
```

This will return all the data in those 2 tables that have the same values for `namaMahasiswa` and `namaKegiatan`.

**Do note:** if you do use `table1.*` and `table2.*` you might not be able to access all the data as the columns will have the same name, so it is **recommended** to always specify all the fields you need to be returned and use `aliases` on the fields that have the same name in both tables.

Ex. `SELECT table1.tingkatan, table2.tingkata AS tingkata2 ....`

But you should really consider adding some sort of a `WHERE` condition to your query so you don't end up wasting to much time in loading your data if you have too many records.

P.S. This is from my best estimate of your table structure as you don't have proper relationships setup on those tables